# Optimizing query by reducing subqueries (more than one alias per subquery, is it possible?)

Tags: mysql

I would like to reduce the number of queries in my main query. As the data is distributed across different tables, I am collecting the necessary information through comparisons with its IDs.

This is my functional query. However, i guess it should be very costly to server performance:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT trtId FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as trtIdOrigem, 
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdOrigem) as trtTituloOrigem, 
    (SELECT treNome FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treNomeOrigem, 
    (SELECT treICAO FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treICAOOrigem, 
    (SELECT treIATA FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treIATAOrigem, 
    (SELECT trtId FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as trtIdDestino, 
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdDestino) as trtTituloDestino, 
    (SELECT treNome FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treNomeDestino, 
    (SELECT treICAO FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treICAODestino, 
    (SELECT treIATA FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treIATADestino,
    (SELECT cidNome FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoCidadeOrigem,
    (SELECT cidAlias FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treAliasCidadeOrigem,
    (SELECT estUF FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cido.estId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoEstadoOrigem,
    (SELECT cidNome FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoCidadeDestino,
    (SELECT cidAlias FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treAliasCidadeDestino,
    (SELECT estUF FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cidd.estId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoEstadoDestino

FROM 
    sistema_voo_operadora vop 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_operadora ope ON vop.opeId = ope.opeId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_voo voo ON vop.vooId = voo.vooId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_voo tiv ON voo.tivId = tiv.tivId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_aeronave aer ON vop.aerId = aer.aerId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_aeronave tia ON aer.tiaId = tia.tiaId

WHERE 
    tiv.tivId = 2 
    AND vooAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vooExcluido = 'N' 
    AND opeAtivo = 'S' 
    AND opeExcluido = 'N' 
    AND vopAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vopExcluido = 'N' 

ORDER BY 
    RAND() 

LIMIT 
    0,4;
```

I wish, at least, that the initial subqueries were grouped in some way. I tried the following, but to no avail (returned Syntax Error):

**Attempt 01:**

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT trtId, treNome, treICAO, treIATA FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as trtIdOrigem, treNomeOrigem, treICAOOrigem, treIATAOrigem 
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdOrigem) as trtTituloOrigem, 
    (SELECT trtId, treNome, treICAO, treIATA FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as trtIdDestino, treNomeDestino, treICAODestino, treIATADestino
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdDestino) as trtTituloDestino, 
    (SELECT cidNome FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoCidadeOrigem,
    (SELECT cidAlias FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treAliasCidadeOrigem,
    (SELECT estUF FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cido.estId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoEstadoOrigem,
    (SELECT cidNome FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoCidadeDestino,
    (SELECT cidAlias FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treAliasCidadeDestino,
    (SELECT estUF FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cidd.estId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoEstadoDestino

FROM 
    sistema_voo_operadora vop 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_operadora ope ON vop.opeId = ope.opeId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_voo voo ON vop.vooId = voo.vooId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_voo tiv ON voo.tivId = tiv.tivId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_aeronave aer ON vop.aerId = aer.aerId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_aeronave tia ON aer.tiaId = tia.tiaId

WHERE 
    tiv.tivId = 2 
    AND vooAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vooExcluido = 'N' 
    AND opeAtivo = 'S' 
    AND opeExcluido = 'N' 
    AND vopAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vopExcluido = 'N' 

ORDER BY 
    RAND() 

LIMIT 
    0,4;
```

**Attempt 02:**

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT trtId as trtIdOrigem as treNomeOrigem, treNome as treNomeOrigem, treICAO as treICAOOrigem, treIATA as treIATAOrigem FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId),
    (SELECT trtId as trtIdDestino, treNome as treNomeDestino, treICAO as treICAODestino, treIATA as treIATADestino FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId),
    (SELECT cidNome as treEnderecoCidadeOrigem, cidAlias as treAliasCidadeOrigem, estUF as treEnderecoEstadoOrigem FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cido.estId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId),
    (SELECT cidNome as treEnderecoCidadeDestino, cidAlias as treAliasCidadeDestino, estUF as treEnderecoEstadoDestino FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cidd.estId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId),
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdOrigem) as trtTituloOrigem, 
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdDestino) as trtTituloDestino

FROM 
    sistema_voo_operadora vop 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_operadora ope ON vop.opeId = ope.opeId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_voo voo ON vop.vooId = voo.vooId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_voo tiv ON voo.tivId = tiv.tivId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_aeronave aer ON vop.aerId = aer.aerId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_aeronave tia ON aer.tiaId = tia.tiaId

WHERE 
    tiv.tivId = 2 
    AND vooAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vooExcluido = 'N' 
    AND opeAtivo = 'S' 
    AND opeExcluido = 'N' 
    AND vopAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vopExcluido = 'N' 

ORDER BY 
    RAND() 

LIMIT 
    0,4;
```

I need to bring 4 records from the sistema_voo_operadora (vop) table.

Inside this, I need to bring the data of the flight (voo), which are in sistema_voo (voo.vooId = vop.vooId)

Inside the sistema_voo table, I save the departure place ID and the destination place ID. The original data is in sistema_trecho (treO for origin, and treD for destination). As I need the city, state and slug of every place still in this query, I had no choice but to make subqueries.

Left joins are required to bring in more external information, such as carrier information, flight type, aircraft used, and aircraft type.

What I can optimize in this query, would save me some hair.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't bring through multiple columns in a subquery that is present in the SELECT clause of your SQL.
2. There is really no reason for subqueries here, just do this via joins. It will be much easier to follow the logic, and it's less stress on your database.

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    vop.*, 
    ope.*,
    voo.*,
    tiv.*,
    aer.*,
    tia.*, 
    treo_origem.trtId as trtIdOrigem, 
    treo_origem.trtTitulo as trtTituloOrigem, 
    treo_origem.treNome as treNomeOrigem, 
    treo_origem.treICAO as treICAOOrigem, 
    treo_origem.treIATA as treIATAOrigem, 
    treo_destino.trtId as trtIdDestino, 
    treo_destino.trtTitulo as trtTituloDestino, 
    treo_destino.treNome as treNomeDestino, 
    treo_destino.treICAO as treICAODestino, 
    treo_destino.treIATA as treIATADestino,
    cido_origem.cidNome as treEnderecoCidadeOrigem,
    cido_origem.cidAlias as treAliasCidadeOrigem,
    cido_origem.estUF as treEnderecoEstadoOrigem,
    cido_destino.cidNome  as treEnderecoCidadeDestino,
    cido_destino.cidAlias  as treAliasCidadeDestino,
    cido_destino.estUF  as treEnderecoEstadoDestino

FROM 
    sistema_voo_operadora vop 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_operadora ope ON vop.opeId = ope.opeId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_voo voo ON vop.vooId = voo.vooId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_voo tiv ON voo.tivId = tiv.tivId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_aeronave aer ON vop.aerId = aer.aerId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_aeronave tia ON aer.tiaId = tia.tiaId
    LEFT JOIN sistemo_trecho treo_origem ON treo_origem.treID = voo.vooOrigemId
    LEFT JOIN sistemo_trecho treo_destino ON treo_destino.treId = voo.vooDestinoId
    LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido_origem ON cido_origem.cidId = treo_origem.cidId
    LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido_destino ON cido_destino.cidID = treo_destino.cidID

WHERE 
    tiv.tivId = 2 
    AND vooAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vooExcluido = 'N' 
    AND opeAtivo = 'S' 
    AND opeExcluido = 'N' 
    AND vopAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vopExcluido = 'N' 

ORDER BY 
    RAND() 

LIMIT 
    0,4;
```

Comment: Woah! I made some little changes on names, and it works! Thank ya!

Comment: Oh yes. I see two of my typos (fixed). My english was slipping through. Glad it helped out!